# In kotlin android 10+ how to make my app disable/enable biometrics authentications of the device like fingerprint?

Tags: android, kotlin, biometrics

Sorry I can't embed code because my computer can't be reached right now

In android 9 and previous I can ask for permission to enable/disable the user biometrics of his device.
But in android 10+ this doesn't work. And it asks me to be a device owner or oner profile. When I searched for how to do that. I figured out that I can just do it from command line only. So is there a way to do this by code. I mean to be a device owner or owner profile?

I tested my code with biometric permission on android 10. I got an exception error indicates I must to be a device owner or have an owner profile to do this.

Comment: "I mean to be a device owner or owner profile?" -- becoming a device owner requires special steps during the device's initial setup. There is no way for an app to become a device owner just by calling some API. "But in android 10+ this doesn't work" -- that seems like a good thing.